# Запись запроса в mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, pdo

допишите пожалуйста код кому не сложно, только с использованием PDO.
Описание:
eсть база данных vote в которой 2 таблицы account и votes.
В таблице votes 6 колонок: id , vote_id, date, nick, votes.
В таблице account 2 колонок: username , vp.
Цель данного скрипта (разделен на 2 этапа): 
1. подключается по адресу -> считывает добавленные строки -> записывает их данные в таблицу votes.
2. если строка добавилась, в таблице account ищет в колонке username нужный nick и добавляет баллы в колонку vote_point в струку с данным ником.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
    $db_host = 'host';
    $db_user = 'login';
    $db_pass = 'pass';
    $db_name = 'vote';
    $encoding = 'utf8';
    $table = 'tabl stat';

    // ссылка на сбор статистики
    $file = 'http://site.ru/';
      $vote = 2; //количество бонусов
      $vip_vote= 4; //количество бонусов 2

    try {
        $dbh = new PDO("mysql:dbname={$db_name};host={$db_host}", $db_user, $db_pass, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES '{$encoding}'"));

        // проверяем, есть ли у нас уже статистика в таблице
        $row = $dbh->query("SELECT MAX(`vote_id`) FROM `{$table}`")->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
        // если есть, то запоминаем максимальный ID
        $last_id = empty($row) ? 0 : $row[0];

        $rows = 0;
        if (($fp = fopen($file, "r")) !== false) {
            while (($data = fgetcsv($fp, 1000, "\t")) !== false) {
                // если в строке не 5 элементов или ID уже есть, то пропускаем строку
                if (count($data) != 5 || $last_id >= $data[0])
                  continue;

                  $fields = array(
                      ':vote_id' => $data[0],
                      ':date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($data[1])),
                      ':ip' => $data[2],
                      ':nick' => $data[3],
                      ':votes' => $data[4],
                  );

                  // сохраняем строку в таблицу
                  $sth = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO `{$table}` (`vote_id`, `date`, `ip`, `nick`, `votes`) VALUES (:vote_id, :date, :ip, :nick, :votes)");
                  if ($sth->execute($fields))
                    $rows ++;
                  else
                    var_dump($sth->errorInfo());
        }
        fclose($fp);
        echo "Добавлено {$rows} записей <br>";
    } else {
        echo 'Ошибка открытия файла';
    }

} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Ошибка подключения: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

на mysqli это выглядит так

```
 $CheckAcc1 = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT username FROM account WHERE username = '$VoteChar'");
    $CheckAcc = mysqli_num_rows($CheckAcc1);

    // Проверяем аккаунт
    if ($CheckAcc > 0) {
        // Статус
        $AccountID1 = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT username FROM account WHERE username = '$VoteChar'");
        $AccountID = mysqli_fetch_row($AccountID1);

        // Проверяем голоса
        $CheckVote1 = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM stat WHERE vote_id = '$VoteID' AND date = '$VoteTime' AND nick = '$VoteChar' AND votes = '$VoteType';");
        $CheckVote = mysqli_num_rows($CheckVote1);

        // Тип голоса
        if ($VoteType == 2) {
            $RewardCoins = $vip_vote;
        }
        else {
            $RewardCoins = $vote;
        }

        // Выдача баллов
        if ($CheckVote <= 0) {
            $Query = mysqli_query($link, "UPDATE account SET vp = vp + $RewardCoins WHERE username = '$AccountID[0]'");
        }
    }
```

Вот что получилось, но в базу table_acc все равно не начисляет бонусы

```
    $db_host = 'host';
    $db_user = 'login';
    $db_pass = 'pass';
    $db_name = 'vote';
    $encoding = 'utf8';
    $table = 'tabl stat';
    $table2 = 'tabl acc';

    // ссылка на сбор статистики
    $file = 'http://site.ru/';
      $vote = 2; //количество бонусов
      $vip_vote= 4; //количество бонусов 2

    try {
        $dbh = new PDO("mysql:dbname={$db_name};host={$db_host}", $db_user, $db_pass, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES '{$encoding}'"));

        // проверяем, есть ли у нас уже статистика в таблице
        $row = $dbh->query("SELECT MAX(`vote_id`) FROM `{$table}`")->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
        // если есть, то запоминаем максимальный ID
        $last_id = empty($row) ? 0 : $row[0];

        $rows = 0;
        if (($fp = fopen($file, "r")) !== false) {
            while (($data = fgetcsv($fp, 1000, "\t")) !== false) {
                // если в строке не 5 элементов или ID уже есть, то пропускаем строку
                if (count($data) != 5 || $last_id >= $data[0])
                  continue;

                  $fields = array(
                      ':vote_id' => $data[0],
                      ':date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($data[1])),
                      ':ip' => $data[2],
                      ':nick' => $data[3],
                      ':votes' => $data[4],
                  );
          if (':votes' == 2) {
            $RewardCoins = $vip_vote;
        }
        else {
            $RewardCoins = $vote;
        }                   
                  // сохраняем строку в таблицу
                  $sth = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO `{$table}` (`vote_id`, `date`, `ip`, `nick`, `votes`) VALUES (:vote_id, :date, :ip, :nick, :votes)");
          $sth1 = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE {$table2} SET vp = vp + $RewardCoins WHERE (username) = :nick AND not exists(select 1 from {$table} where vote_id = :vote_id AND date = :date AND nick = :nick AND votes = :votes)");
                  if ($sth->execute($fields))
                    $rows ++;
                  else
                    var_dump($sth->errorInfo());
        }
        fclose($fp);
        echo "Добавлено {$rows} записей <br>";
    } else {
        echo 'Ошибка открытия файла';
    }

} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Ошибка подключения: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: prepare достаточно делать один раз перед циклом. так работать будет заметно быстрее. В этом и есть основная суть этих действий. Запрос компилируется MySQL один раз, а потом много раз выполняется

Comment: Что касается второй части, то она никак с первой не стыкуется и переписана ни каким образом быть не может. потому что в первой части не достаточно информации для этого. Например VoteType отсутствует и брать его неоткуда. И кстати вторую часть перед тем как переписывать на PDO надо вообще сократить до пары строк. первые два select делаются практически вхлостую. Результаты того, что идет вторым, вообще равны первому. И Все эти действия можно перенести сразу в запрос update

Comment: VoteType данные переменной в первом скрипте вверху. А так она сравнивает последнюю колонку на значение 1 или 2  $VoteType = substr($VoteDB[4],0,1); -1 это $vote а 2 это $vip_vote

Comment: Странно, у меня видимо что не то с клавиатурой и монитором. Я ищу на всей странице с вопросом упоминания VoteType или VoteDB... VoteType упоминается только во втором скрипте и его значение не задано. VoteDB, из которого его можно было бы получить, вообще не упоминается. Подозреваю что ваш монитор показывает вам совершенно другую картину

Comment: Так как в верхней части эти все VoteType не упоминаются, значит они для него константы и ими можно пренебречь. Тогда предлагаю в цикле вставки собирать в массив все ... А кстати, что собирать то же не ясно. В первом скрипте еще и VoteChar не упоминается. Ладно, предположим это nick...

Comment: Тогда собираем в массив все nick. А после загрузки всех данных пишем один единственный `update ... set vp=vp+case when VoteType=2 then Vip_vote else Vote end where nick in(?,?,...,??) and exists(select 1 from account where ....)` Вопросительных знаков надо сделать столько сколько значений в массиве ников, а сам массив в этот запрос передать как параметр

Comment: Mike спасибо за комментарии, и извиняюсь что не написал больше подробностей. Дело в том что сайт удаленный, а скрипт находиться на сервере и работает с кроном раз в час включается и проверяет на обновления массив на сайте. Если пользователь зашел на сайт и оставил свои данные добавляется строчка с его: уникальным номером, дата\время, ip,  ником и голосом. Сработал скрипт по крону и если его номер уникальный дописал в tabl_stat и дал ему свой номер, а в tabl_acc нашел в колонке username нашел его nick и добавил +1 или +2 вп в зависимости от его голоса на удаленном сайт,in(?,?,,??)не сработает

Comment: Ну значит все таки на каждого отдельный update. Но одним действием все равно вполне можно обойтись, что то вроде `UPDATE account SET vp = vp + :RewardCoins WHERE username = :nick AND not exists(select 1 from stat where vote_id = :VoteID AND date = :VoteTime AND nick = :nick AND votes = :VoteType)`. Опять же, перед циклом один раз делаете prepare такого запроса, в отдельную переменную конечно, (т.е. у вас 2 заранее готовых запроса $sth тот что insert делает, и $sth1 этот). И внутри цикла его выполняете execute, передавая массив с нужными данными

Comment: Mike посмотрите я внес изменения в код, но не добавляет балы по прежнему

Comment: А где у вас sth1->execute(...) ? И я так подозреваю он должен быть перед insert иначе условие not exists найдет строку которую вы только что вставили и никакого update не будет. А оба prepare, все таки вынесите из цикла, поставьте перед `while (($data = fgetcsv($fp, 1000, "\t")) !== false) {` внутри цикла только execute

Comment: И кстати `if (':votes' == 2) {` никогда не отработает. Строка `:votes` это просто строка и более ничего. И она разумеется не равна 2. Просто $data[4]==2 проверяйте

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю надо что то в этом роде:

```
   if (($fp = fopen($file, "r")) !== false) {
        // Готовим запросы один раз. Это значительно ускоряет выполнение
        $sth = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO `{$table}` (`vote_id`, `date`, `ip`, `nick`, `votes`) VALUES (:vote_id, :date, :ip, :nick, :votes)");
        $sth1 = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE {$table2} SET vp = vp + :RewardCoins WHERE username = :nick AND not exists(select 1 from {$table} where vote_id = :vote_id AND date = :date AND nick = :nick AND votes = :votes)");


        while (($data = fgetcsv($fp, 1000, "\t")) !== false) {
            // если в строке не 5 элементов или ID уже есть, то пропускаем строку
            if (count($data) != 5 || $last_id >= $data[0]) continue;

             $fields = array(
                  ':vote_id' => $data[0],
                  ':date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($data[1])),
                  ':nick' => $data[3],
                  ':votes' => $data[4],
                  ':RewardCoins' => ($data[4]==2 ? $vip_vote : $vote)
              );
              $sth1->execute($fields); // Обновляем VP
              $fields[':ip']=$data[2]; // Добавляем ip для следующего запроса
              unset($fields[':RewardCoins']); // А это поле удаляем, т.к. в следующем запросе его нет
              // сохраняем строку в таблицу
              if ($sth->execute($fields)) $rows ++;
              else var_dump($sth->errorInfo()); // Если у вас на соединении стоит выбрасывание исключения, то эта строка никогда не выполнится, т.к. при ошибке мы вылетим в блок catch
    }
    fclose($fp);
    echo "Добавлено {$rows} записей <br>";
} else {
    echo 'Ошибка открытия файла';
}
```

Comment: Спасибо этот скрипт работает хорошо } catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Ошибка подключения: ' . $e->getMessage();
} в конце не хватает, есть немного не понятных моментов сейчас попробую разорбратся

Comment: Mike проверил скрипт работает хорошо, но есть баг если в в колонке vp, стоит число к примеру 2 то при работе скрипта, он обновляет становиться 4. Однако если там пусто, то он не добавляет в него баллы и оставляет пустым. Её параметры `vp`  varchar(32) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL

Comment: @Олег значит `update {$table2} SET vp = coalesce(vp, 0) + ...`

Comment: Mike Спасибо огромного, это гениально, все работает как швейцарские часы !

Comment: @Олег только не `echo 'Ошибка подключения: ' . $e->getMessage();` а `throw new \PDOException($e->getMessage(), (int)$e->getCode());`, и не в конце, а только вокруг new PDO. См. https://phpdelusions.net/pdo_examples/connect_to_mysql