# Как добавить в БД и изменить имя фала на md5 циклом?

Tags: php

Есть папка Audio в ней находятся mp3 файлы. Нужно переместить в папку music и сохранить в базе данных имя файла в md5 (81fbbf61e355f9013589c8ea750120d9.mp3) название из первоначального названия файла(Monochrom Inc.  Stereo MC's - Bring It On.mp3) и записать в БД, в название какое было из начально имя файла и конвертированный файл.

```
 $a ="Monochrom Inc.  Stereo MC's - Bring It On";
 $b ="81fbbf61e355f9013589c8ea750120d9.mp3"

 $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);

 $imp = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO `Audio` (`id`, `trackname`, `url`, `dataadd`) 
 VALUES (NULL, '.$a.', '.$b.', UTC_DATE());");
```

В папке больше 10000 тыс. файлов как их все переименовать, и переложить в другую папку и записать в БД?

Comment: У вас в приведенном коде проблема с кавычками. Имя файла содержит кавычку, значит вы не можете просто так поместить переменную $a в запрос. Не подставляйте значения переменных непосредственно в текст запроса. Используйте привязку значений. Посмотрите как работают с БД в официальных примерах к PDO https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php

Comment: А что касательно вашего вопроса, то делаете цикл на основе readdir https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php и в нем собственно получаете md5 от имен, пишите в БД и потом переименовываете файл на диске

Comment: @Mike Это понятно. Мне не понятно другое как массив полученных файлов записать в бузу данных и обрезать в PHP расширение? В JS  как то проще тут понять не чего не могу. Второй месяц как начал заниматься изучением PHP не заходит он мне.

Comment: массив писать по одной записи. перед началом цикла while делаете один раз prepare для insert с подставляемыми занчениями. А внутри цикла, который обрабатывает очередной файл вызываете execute передавая ему нужные переменные для подстановки в запрос. А расширение можно отрезать preg_replace например

Comment: Вот пример как из входного файла данные в БД писать https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/942226/194569 А у вас вся разница только в том, что цикл будет по директории идти, а не по содержимому файла

Comment: @Mike Буду пробовать)))