# Обновление массива данных в MySQL PHP

Tags: php, mysql, массивы, html5, update

Сделал вывод таблицы, которую можно редактировать, добавив в `<td>` теги `<input>`. Все это дело для обновления в MySQL, при изменение данных, `<td>` и `<input>` поместил в `<form>`, которая через метод `POST` оправляет данные

```
<form action="resave.php" method="post">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">Код</th>
        <th scope="col">Продукт</th>
        <th scope="col">Цена</th>
        <th scope="col">Принято</th>
        <th scope="col">Сдано</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <?php $query = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM product"); ?>
      <?php while ($result = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) { ?>
      <tr>
        <th><input type="text" name="id[]" value="<?php echo $result['id']; ?>"></th>
        <td><input type="text" name="nameProduct[]" value="<?php echo $result['nameProduct']; ?>"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="price[]" value="<?php echo $result['price']; ?>"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="accepted[]" value="<?php echo $result['accepted']; ?>"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="delivered[]" value="<?php echo $result['delivered']; ?>"></td>
      </tr>
      <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <button type="submit">Сохранить</button>
</form>
```

Обработчик `resave.php` приведен ниже. Функции плохо освоил, поэтому copy/paste. 
Строчка `echo '[' . $key . '] => ' . $value . '<br>';` в цикле `foreach`, выводила содержимое массивов, `echo '<hr>';` визуально разделяла вывод цикла

```
    <?php
    require_once('connection.php');

    // Error
    ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);   

    if (isset($_POST['id']) && isset($_POST['nameProduct']) && isset($_POST['price']) && 
isset($_POST['accepted']) && isset($_POST['delivered'])) {

      $id = $_POST['id'];                        // Идентификатор
      $nameProduct = $_POST['nameProduct'];      // Имя товара
      $price = $_POST['price'];                  // Цена
      $accepted = $_POST['accepted'];            // Принято
      $delivered = $_POST['delivered'];          // Сдано


      foreach($id as $key => $value) {
        //echo '[' . $key . '] => ' . $value . '<br>';

        $query = "UPDATE product SET id = '".$value."' WHERE id = '".$key."'";
        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
      }

      //echo '<hr>';

      foreach($nameProduct as $key => $value) {
        //echo '[' . $key . '] => ' . $value . '<br>';

        $query = "UPDATE product SET nameProduct = '".$value."' WHERE id = '".$key."'";
        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);    
      }

      //echo '<hr>';

      foreach($price as $key => $value) {
        //echo '[' . $key . '] => ' . $value . '<br>';

        $query = "UPDATE product SET price = '".$value."' WHERE id = '".$key."'";
        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
      }

      //echo '<hr>';

      foreach($accepted as $key => $value) {
        //echo '[' . $key . '] => ' . $value . '<br>';

        $query = "UPDATE product SET accepted = '".$value."' WHERE id = '".$key."'";
        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);    
      }

      //echo '<hr>';

      foreach($delivered as $key => $value) {
         //echo '[' . $key . '] => ' . $value . '<br>';

        $query = "UPDATE product SET delivered = '".$value."' WHERE id = '".$key."'";
        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
      }

      //echo '<hr>';

  if ($result) {
        echo '<div class="container"><div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
        Данные сохранены!</div></div>';
  } else {
        echo '<div class="container"><div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
        Данные не сохранены!</div></div>';
  }

  require_once('index.php');
}
?>
```

Таблица состоит из таких столбцов. Столбец `currentDate varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL` нигде не фигурирует в данном случае

```
CREATE TABLE `product` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `nameProduct` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `price` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `accepted` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `delivered` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `currentDate` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Сохранение происходит, однако `foreach` сохраняет данные относительно не `id` которое в таблице, а относительно `key` ключа массива. Из-за этого при сохранении самая первая стройка таблицы в `MySQL` удаляется, вместо последней добавляется строчка с данными `(Array)`.

Предполагаю это из-за того, что индекс ключей массива начинается с `0`, поэтому первая строчка удаляется в таблице. Как мне правильно сохранить массив данных не по `key` массива, а по `id` таблицы которую вывел, после хочу пересохранить?

Comment: для начала уберите форме во всех name скобки [] чтоб было name="id" и т.д.

Comment: @МаксМаксимус Наоборот

Comment: пробегайте циклом один массив и используйте его ключи для доступа ко всем остальным массивам, так как они идут параллельно. Т.е. используйте внутри цикла `$id[$key]`, `$nameProduct[$key]` и т.д. и пишите все поля единым `update ... where id=$id[$key]`. А вообще код надо серьезно переделать, на предмет того, что бы не подставлять значения принятых полей непосредственно в запрос, иначе вас взломают SQL-инъекцией. Всегда используйте подготовленные выражения https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: @Ипатьев да верно. не заметил цикл.

Comment: Не разобрался как комментарии сделать конкретно определенному пользователю. Если удалю с HTML "[]" в POST придет не массив, а последняя выведенная строчка в HTML. После цикл foreach будет жаловаться на не верный аргумент. "var_dump" покажет, что действительно, там не массив, а одно значение

Comment: Это учебный проект, он вряд ли в сети будет, максимум на бесплатном хостинге, и пользоваться им буду только я. Мой уровень для коммерческой деятельность очень скромный

Comment: По поводу SQL-инъекцией, согласен, хочу PDO  освоить, пока стандартные способы хочу освоить, и ООП-шным синтаксисом писать

Comment: в плане организации кода, я бы лучше создал функцию которая возвращала бы выборку из таблицы table, а в нужном месте делал foreach полученного массива (`foreach(getProducts()) as $k => $v{}`). и лучше все таки делать через PDO::prepare https://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdo.prepare.php

Comment: Mike, спасибо за совет написать единым запросом, и за совет с подготовленными выражениями, пока это буду разбирать, PDO успеется. Еще раз спасибо!

Comment: @Макс Максимус, спасибо за мысль, пытаюсь функцию написать подобную. У меня запросы хромают и цикл foreach. Оказывается foreach не такой страшный, если им не пытаться форму "валидировать", хах)

Comment: @StudyingAgain PDO от mysqli не сильно отличается. А подготовленные выражения там гораздо приятнее. В mysqli очень громоздко, prepare, потом bind с указанием типов данных, execute и наконец fetch (если нужен). А в PDO bind не нужны, можно параметры массивом прямо в execute передавать, гораздо лаконичнее выходит

Comment: @StudyingAgain Вот пример массовой записи на PDO нашел. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/942226/194569 Обратите внимание, prepare выполняется один раз перед циклом, а внутри только execute. Это еще и ускоряет работу, так как БД не надо каждый раз запрос разбирать.

Comment: @Mike, соглашусь, лаконичнее выглядит. Не все увы понять смогу на данный момент с примера. Хотя функцию `fopen` например использовал для записи данных в файл. Правда массово не научился, построчно только, указывая строго номер строки на которую нужно записать данные. PDO надо осваивать, в моей учебной базе 1000 записей товаров разной категории. Еще живой поиск хочу сделать, чтоб найти нужный товар, изменить что-то, и сохранить. Плюс сейчас в таблицу(HTML) выводится все что есть, то есть все 1000 записей, полотнище целое, не знаю как интерфейс организовать.

Comment: Ну там пример по чтению из файла, а по чему цикл то файлу или массиву из post, это уже детали

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 foreach($id as $key => $value) {
    $query = "UPDATE product SET nameProduct = ".$nameProduct[$key].
         "', price = '".$price[$key].
         "', accepted = '".$accepted[$key].
         "', delivered = '".$delivered[$key]."' WHERE id = '".$id[$key]."'";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
 }
```

Comment: В подготовленные выражения не умеем?

Comment: Всё-таки конечно уровень помогаек на стаковерфлое чудовищно низкий, и это печально

Comment: где же ваш ответ если ваш уровень так высок? Я с удовольствием оценю его

Comment: IvaMuxa, спасибо за ответ в примере, одной кавычки " ' " не хватало данные не сохранялись. Работает как хотел, спасибо!

Comment: Увы мои голоса не считаются, не достаточная репутация

Comment: Ну я надеюсь что главное в моём ответе вы уловили как использовать $key ко всем массивам сразу

Comment: @IvaMuxa, разобрался конечно. Не мог понять как запись правильно сделать, например не доходило, что вот так `$nameProduct[$key]` в принципе то написать возможно в данном случае. Массивы не скроешь, так же просто мной пройдены для галочки